# How do i get a list of Java Developer in San Francisco using the GitHub API

Tags: json, github-api

I succesfully got a list of 30 profiles using https://api.github.com/users

How can i get a List of Profiles Of JAVA developers in San Francisco?

Comment: https://api.github.com/search/users?q=location:san%20francisco+language:java gets you close based on https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-users

Comment: Ok Got it.Thanks